# Create Flow Charts in React js using Fluent UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluent-ui

I want to create a flow chart with buttons in react js using Fluent UI.

However, I am not getting anything in Fluent UI in the context of Flow Charts.

Can anyone help me with this?

Below is how I wish to make my chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any native flow chart within Fluent UI but you should be able to use a library like [React Flow](https://reactflow.dev/).